# How can I correctly map multiple url-patterns to spring dispatcher?

Tags: spring, rest, servlets, spring-mvc

I want to add a rest service to a spring app. The dispatcher is currently configured to serve only *.do paths, which isn't really compatible with rest paths so I've added an additional pattern like so

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>timetabling</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>timetabling</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When I hit my rest controller I see

```
08-01-2013 15:26:13,075 [23198170@qtp-12556818-9] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound  1080 WARN  No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/timetabling/rest/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'timetabling'
```

If I change the mapping like so

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>timetabling</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I get

```
08-01-2013 15:28:33,664 [13327669@qtp-4725080-0] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping  220 DEBUG Returning handler method [public java.lang.String edu.ucl.isd.timetabling.web.controller.RestController.test(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
```

Which leads me to suspect there's something wrong with the way I'm specifying the mapping but I can't see what it is. Unfortunately I can't use the second form as this breaks other areas of the app, I need to have separate mappings can anyone spot the problem?

for completeness here's a snip of my rest service but seeing as this does work correctly with the root mapping I don't think the problem is here

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/rest")
public class RestController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String test() {
         return "rest service is alive";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `@RequestMapping("/rest")` on your controller and @RequestMapping("/") on your method with a servlet mapping of `/rest/*` a request of `/rest/rest/` would get correctly dispatched to your `test()` method not `/rest/`, if you want `/rest` to reach your test() method, then it will be better to remove the @RequestMapping from the controller and retain it only on the method.

Comment: Right, of course, I'd failed to realise that we're dealing with two completely different pattern matching systems here. I changed the url-pattern to /mvc/* so now I have my rest service at /mvc/rest/ . Thanks very much.